# Remove App Widget programmatically when its corresponding item is deleted

Tags: android, kotlin, android-widget

My App has a recyclerView and each recyclerView Item can have its Widget. The problem is when the user deletes the item of recyclerView its corresponding Widget remains on the Home Screen which is not working anymore. Is there any way to remove App Widget programmatically when a user deletes the item from the App, I have widget ID.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do but you want to remove any widget from XML page, you can add all corresponding Widget in a layout, and just remove the whole layout. So all the inner Widget of the layout will be removed.

Comment: @PratikSatani Its an app widget which you can get by long press on the home screen and then select the widget.

Comment: Okay, .i got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add or remove app widgets from the home screen. Only the user can do that.

Any app widgets tied to a deleted account could show a different account, or adopt some "(account deleted)" look that would trigger the user to get rid of the app widget or reconfigure it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already know this Answer by Sir CommonsWare but I didn't get a clear idea of what is the solution then. So I guess there is no way to delete the widget :( I will accept your answer but I will wait a little bit more.
Thanks :)